# Custom JTableHeader causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, jtableheader

I've been trying to use the code from [Oracle's How To Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#headertooltip) to create a JTable with tool tips for each column header.  [The demo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableToolTipsDemoProject/src/components/TableToolTipsDemo.java) seems to work but whether I paste the code in directly or abstract my own class, I get a **NullPointerException** on a call to **getTableCellRendererComponent()** in **SynthTableHeaderUI.java** line 233. This is due to a call to **header.getTable()** which returns null on any table I try to **setTableHeader()** on, even if I setTableHeader(new JTableHeader(tblWhatever.getColumnModel()));

The function I pasted from the demo is inside a custom TableModel that otherwise works very well and looks like this:

```
public class TestTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
private final String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Height", "Weight", "Age"};
private final String[] columnToolTips = {"Person's Name",
                                     "Height in centimetres.",
                                     "Weight in kilograms.",
                                     "Age in years as of 2015-Jan-01."};
private ToolTipTableHeader ClientTableHeader; // = new ToolTipTableHeader((new JTable()).getColumnModel(), columnToolTips);

    private final Client[] List = {
        new Client("Abigale", 150, 108, 22),
        new Client("Bob", 180, 175, 36),
        new Client("Charles", 150, 210, 52)
    };

    /*
     * Constructors
     */
    public TestTableModel() {
        super();
    }

    public void setTableHeader(JTable tblClients) {
        tblClients.setTableHeader(createDefaultTableHeader(tblClients.getColumnModel()));
    }

    /*
     * AbstractCellEditor Implementations
     */
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int col) throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        switch(col) {
            case 0: return String.class;  //.ClientName;
            case 1: return Integer.class; //.Height;
            case 2: return Integer.class; //.Weight;
            case 3: return Integer.class; //.Age;
            default: throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Column " + col + ": class not accounted for in " + this.getClass().getName() + ".getColumnClass");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.length; }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) { return columnNames[col]; }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() { return List.length; }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        switch(col) {
            case 0: return List[row].ClientName;
            case 1: return List[row].Height;
            case 2: return List[row].Weight;
            case 3: return List[row].Age;
            default: throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Column " + col + ": value not accounted for in " + this.getClass().getName() + ".getValueAt");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) { return true; }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        switch(col) {
            case 0: List[row].ClientName = (String) value; break;
            case 1: List[row].Height = (Integer) value; break;
            case 2: List[row].Weight = (Integer) value; break;
            case 3: List[row].Age = (Integer) value; break;
            default: throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Column " + col + ": value not accounted for in " + this.getClass().getName() + ".setValueAt");
        }
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    /*
     * Extensions
     */

    //Implement table header tool tips.
    protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader(TableColumnModel tcmThis) {
        return new JTableHeader(tcmThis) {
            @Override
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
                String tip = null;
                java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
                int index = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(p.x);
                int realIndex = 
                        columnModel.getColumn(index).getModelIndex();
                return columnToolTips[realIndex];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The custom class looks like this:

```
public class ToolTipTableHeader extends JTableHeader {
    private final String ColumnToolTips[];

    ToolTipTableHeader(TableColumnModel cm, String iniToolTips[]) {
        super(cm);

        if(iniToolTips.length != cm.getColumnCount()) 
            throw new InvalidParameterException("The size of iniToolTips must be precisely equal to the columnModel column count.");
        ColumnToolTips = iniToolTips;
    }

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent meToolTipEvent) {
        String tip = null;
        if(columnModel == null) return "columnModel == null";
        if(meToolTipEvent == null) return "meMouseEvent == null";
        Point p = meToolTipEvent.getPoint();
        int index = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(p.x);
        int realIndex = columnModel.getColumn(index).getModelIndex();
        return ColumnToolTips[realIndex];
    }
}
```

The initialization is done in a **JDialog** constructor (the **JTable tblTest** is created in the designer):

```
public TestForm(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();

    TestTableModel htmTest = new TestTableModel();
    tblTest.setModel(new TestTableModel());
    htmTest.setTableHeader(tblTest);
}
```

I notice the constructor for a default JTableHeader doesn't require a JTable be passed to it, and I've implemented a constructor and an overridden **getTable()** which doesn't seem to be called.  As I write this I realize that the demo that works puts the function inside a custom **JTable**, which I don't want to do because I'm using NetBeans IDE and I don't know a simple way to add a custom table to the designer.

What am I missing?  How do I implement this without creating a custom **JTable**?  Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: I would remove all references to JTable, including the thisTable field and the constructor which takes a JTable.  Remove the override of getTable().  JTableHeader already has getTable and setTable methods;  don't interfere with them.  Your code appears to have no use for thisTable anyway.  Of course, once you do that, your class will look nearly identical to the anonymous class in the Oracle example… which it should.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  VGR, I agree that JTableHeader already implements that, and my own code has no need of it. The overridden getTable() function and supporting code are recent additions, to attempt to cope with the error message.  I get the same thing with or without it.

Comment: Andrew Thompson, thanks for the nomenclature and references.  I thought I'd done so, though I admit I hadn't created a separate project to verify the functionality.  I'll do so & update my post.

Comment: Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify the person of a new comment.  *"I'll do so & update my post."*  An MCVE needs to be one source file (which might contain more than one class) with imports and a `main(String[])` to run it.  Don't make the mistake of thinking that MCVE just means 'minimal'..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Argh, heh heh!  OK ... I've been using the IDE so not sure how to do the one-source thing.  Easy to paste everything into one file but I'm not sure what would be needed in the main(String[]) function to make it run.  With apologies, I think I'll leave it as-is for now but remember for future questions.

Comment: **update**: I used the _Custom_Creaton_Code_ option in NetBeans IDE to add the demo's original **createDefaultTableHeader** function and it worked.  This will let my project go ahead but seems inelegant to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **JTableHeader** extension **must** be added as part of the construction of the **JTable**. Any subsequent setting of the table header results in the above error.  If using NetBeans, go to *Design Mode* for the dialog/form/panel, select the table in question and click the *Code Tab* of the *Properties* window. Add (for example)

```
new javax.swing.JTable() {
    //Implement table header tool tips.
    protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
        return new JTableHeader(columnModel) {
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
                String tip = null;
                java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
                int index = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(p.x);
                int realIndex =  columnModel.getColumn(index).getModelIndex();
                return myToolTips[realIndex];
            }
        };
    }
};
```

to the *Custom Creation Code* field and be sure to define

```
private final String[] myToolTips = {
    "Column 0 tool tip",
    "Column 1 tool tip",
    // ...
    "Final column tool tip"
};
```

somewhere in the dialog/form/panel's class.  This works but is still a bit inelegant in that it needs to be done for every form that uses that table model, rather than being able to meld that in and have a single class that sets up the table.